# How does ActiveRecord infer mapping from singular (class) and plural (table); and is it possible to override?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, orm, activerecord, naming-conventions

How does ActiveRecord infer mapping from singular (class) and plural (table) for example:

```
People = Person
Ducks = Duck
Geese = Goose 
Categories = Category
```

Seems like a nice idea in concept, but no idea if I have to map the singular (class) and plural (table) instances, or if ActiveRecord is some how "magically" doing this. Plus, seems like this might lead to more overhead when having to pluralize a name that's not as simple as just adding "s".

**NOTE:** Moved the second part of this question here: [Does ActiveRecord assign a key to every table using the naming convention “ID”, and if so, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422042/does-activerecord-assign-a-key-to-every-table-using-the-naming-convention-id-a)

Comment: These are pretty fundamental questions to be asking. There's a lot to know about ActiveRecord, and it's hard to do things correctly without having read up on the basics. Good luck.

Comment: @fullware: They're not fundamental questions, in fact - I'm not aware of any other system that dynamically pluralizes objects in an attempt to achieve some sort of semantic cohesion; English itself doesn't even pluralizes things in a consistent way. In fact, if I'm unable to find a good reason not to, I'm turning the "feature" off by setting ever class/table as "inflect.uncountable"; since that's way, way easier than thinking about a extra rule that's not based on a highly inconsistent English language.

Comment: Fundamental to Rails was the implication here. You might solicit some other opinions as to whether disabling features that are part of the "Rails Way" will be well-received by other developers you may have to work with. Nobody is 100% happy with the way things are done, but personally I end up regretting when I try to fight a framework rather than to work with it.

Comment: @fullware: Yep, I know - but sometimes you learning more by not going with the flow. Plus, I know that these sorts of questions are likely to give me a quick read of the flexibility of the framework itself; which it has in some small way. FYI, gave you +2 for giving input. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rails uses the ActiveSupport::Inflector to keep track of words and how to change them. For example, Rails will know to store UserPreference in user_preferences

You can also add your one inflections to the inflector to handle weirder cases where adding an s does not make sense.

In /config/initializers/inflections.rb you get the following:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.plural /^(ox)$/i, '\1en'
  inflect.singular /^(ox)en/i, '\1'
  inflect.irregular 'person', 'people'
  inflect.uncountable %w( fish sheep )
end
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html

Comment: +1 Great, thanks -- made the question just one question, and selecting you as the answer. Moved the other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422042/does-activerecord-assign-a-key-to-every-table-using-the-naming-convention-id-a